# jQuery plugin combining a thumbnail gellery with a 3D image sequence viewer?

Tags: jquery, gallery, 360-degrees

I want the functionality of those two plugins combined:

- [Reel plugin](http://jquery.vostrel.cz/reel)
- [Gallerific](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/)

I found this one but it costs 99$: [AJAX ZOOM](http://www.ajax-zoom.com/)

An alternative would be to use a thumbnail gallery plugin that allows any html content to be in its items.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this

http://lukedurrant.com/2011/08/apples-360-rotating-ipod-html-5-source-code-download/